# Using an array to make a table

Tags: tables, arrays

This is similar to my previous question but I can't quite figure out the order of things. Here is the code I'd like to use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{arydshln,bigstrut}

\begin{document}
 \begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
\hline
0 & \bar 0_n & \bar 0_{(m+1)} \\ 
\hline
d & \bar c &\multirow{-4}{*}{$I_{(m+1)}$} \\ 
\cdashline{1-2}
A & & b \\
 & &  \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

What it looks like now:

[image]

What it needs to look like:

[image]

I'd like to understand how this is set up. I will be needing to make several of these tables but, for example, sometimes the A box will be at the top, or middle bottom, or top right. Does `bigstrut` need to change when the first column needs to move all the way to the right (for sizing). When do you use the `&&`? Is `multirow` in the right spot?

Comment: ...I've updated your question to only include the necessary packages to replicate the results. Do the same next time you post a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array, arydshln, multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{array}{|>{\bm}c| *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\bm$}p{24mm}<{$}|} }
    \hline
0       &   \hat{0}_n   &   \hat{0}_{(m+1)}     \\
        \hline
d       &   \hat c      &                       \\
    \cdashline{1-2}
        &               &                       \\
\bar{b} &   A           &                       \\
        &               &   \multirow{-4.2}{*}{\centering
                            ${I}_{(m+1)}$}   \\                       
    \hline
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! what does the bm package do?

Comment: @ErikaOlsen: See the [`bm` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/bm).

Comment: @Sebastiano, it was there but code was bad formatted :-(. Corrected now. Thank you very much to point me on this.

Comment: @ErikaOlsen, `bm` packages is for bold  math font I guess (from your image in question), that you like to have them in table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve the same, using phantom heights to force a certain height of the rows, and fixed width columns to set the column width.

Also, nested arrays ensure that the vertical alignments is stable, even if you add rows to the nested arrays, or change they height with other mean. For example, if you prefer a higher last row, you just changes 1.75 cm to 2 cm in the `\DD` command, and the alignment if the last cell (with the formulae adjust automatically).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\def\DD{\vphantom{\parbox[c][1.75cm]{10pt}{-}}}
\def\DS{\vphantom{\parbox[c][0.75cm]{10pt}{-}}}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{array}{|c|c|>{$}wc{\dimexpr(2cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth)}<{$}|}
\hline
\DS 0 & \bar 0_n & \bar 0_{(m+1)} \\ 
\hline
    \begin{array}{c}
    \DS d  \\
    \cdashline{1-1}
    \DD \bar b \\
    \end{array} &
    \begin{array}{>{$}wc{2cm}<{$}}
     \DS \hat c  \\
     \cdashline{1-1}
     \DD A \\
     \end{array} & 
I_{(m+1)} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```