# Content of two boxes in an array table are not in the correct spot

Tags: tables, arrays

I am so close to getting these array tables down but am having trouble with the first 2 lines. The A should be in the middle top row and the first box doesn't even show up in the table.

Here is what the table looks like now:
[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, arydshln, multirow, bigstrut}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
 \hline
 \multirow{-4.2}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$} & &   \\
 A & & \hat{b} \\
& & \\
\cdashline{2-3}
& \bar{c} & d \\
\hline
\bar{0_(m + 1)} & \bar{0_n} & 0 \\
\hline
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

This is what it should look like:
[image]

I'm getting confused with what line everything should be on and when I'm supposed to use extra &'s.

Comment: Is it for the `\bar`  above some symbols? Simply use `\bar{0}_{m+1}`  and  `\bar{0}_{n}`, i.e; do not include the indices in the `\bar` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the following is closer to what you want to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, arydshln, multirow, bigstrut}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
 \hline
 \multirow{4}{*}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$} & &   \\
& A &  \hat{b} \\
& & \\
\cdashline{2-3}
& \bar{c} & d \\
\hline
\bar{0}_{(m + 1)} & \bar{0}_{n} & 0 \\
\hline
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

[image]

In the next MWE as base I consider [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520108/using-an-array-to-make-a-table) on your previous question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, arydshln, multirow}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{array}{|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{24mm}<{$}|}c| }
    \hline
                &                           &           \\
I_{(m+1)}       & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$A$}   & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$\hat{b}$}\\
    \cdashline{2-3}
                & \bar{c}                   &   d       \\
    \hline
\bar{0}_{(m+1)} & \bar{0}_n                 &   0       \\
    \hline
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? (with some `\extrarowheight`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, arydshln, multirow, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{array}{|>{\centering\bigstrut$}p{3cm}<{$}|>{\centering$}p{3cm}<{$}|c|}
 \hline
 \multirow{5}{=}{\centering ${I}_{(m+1)}$} & & \\
 & A & \hat{b} \\
& & \\
\cdashline{2-3}
& \bar{c} & d \\
\hline
\bar{0}_{(m + 1)} & \bar{0}_{n} & 0 \\
\hline
 \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]